# Скрипт команда для принудительного запуска .ink .exe от имени администратора в обход доменного контроля и групповых политик

Tags: windows, active-directory, exe, uac

Скрипт команда для принудительного запуска .ink .exe от имени администратора в обход доменного контроля и групповых политик.
Суть в том что пользователю приходится каждый раз вводить пароль администратора, ему это не удобно, локального администратора выдавать нельзя! 
Существует ли скрипт\команда по FORCE запуску любой программы в доменной сети?
Пишите Ваши варианты.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если надо именно под учеткой админа (пароль запросит один раз, потом спрашивать не будет):

> runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator "c:\myExeFile.exe"

2. Если имеется в виду "от имени админа":

2а) создать ярлык и в свойствах в "дополнительно" поставить галочку "запуск от имени админа"

2б) интегрировать в exe манифест с прописанными правами

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

для этого понадобится windows sdk. внедрять так:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\mt.exe" -manifest C:\mymanifest -outputresource:C:\myExeFile.exe;#1

Comment: Windows SDK от любой версии?

Comment: должно быть в любой